# ASPxGridView EditForm Customization

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, customization, edit, aspxgridview

I have Created a GridView, and i want to customize the edit form. I need to hide/delete or arrange the items on the edit from. For example to move a text box from the the top left side to the bottom right side, or delete from the edit form.

It is possible?

```
<EditForm>
            <div style="padding: 4px 4px 3px 4px">
                <dx:ASPxPageControl runat="server" ID="pageControl1" Width="100%" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                    <TabPages>
                        <dx:TabPage Text="Edit" Visible="true">
                            <ContentCollection>
                                <dx:ContentControl ID="ContentControl1" runat="server">
                                    <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="Edit" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ReplacementType="EditFormEditors"
                                        runat="server">
                                    </dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
                                    <div style="text-align: right; padding: 2px">
                                        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="UpdateButton" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton"
                                            runat="server">
                                        </dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
                                        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="CancelButton" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton"
                                            runat="server">
                                        </dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
                                    </div>
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>

                        <dx:TabPage Text="Edit2" Visible="true">
                            <ContentCollection>
                                <dx:ContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>

                    </TabPages>
                </dx:ASPxPageControl>
        </EditForm>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey V.B. I have an idea of organizing the Edit Form. Can you give me sample list of your columns for more detailed answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Ruchi Doshi. My idea is, that this Edit Form organizing to be able to work with any data. For example now i have a test data table which has 4 columns(Id,Name,Description and Date). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  This can be done by defining the ASPxGridView's EditFormTemplate.  There are two demo projects showing how this can be done:

[Grid Editing - Edit Form Template](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditFormTemplate.aspx)

[Grid Editing - Two-Way Binding](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/TwoWayBinding.aspx)

Here is the help topic which should also might be helpful to you:

[GridViewTemplates.EditForm Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewTemplates_EditFormtopic)

Comment: Thanks Platon.
But these demo projects won't help me. The idea is like on the first project that you have attached, an edit form like that, but i want to move these element for example with an drag and drop. For example, after edit form is opened, with a mouse click, i want to move the first name text box after Title text box.

Comment: If you use EditForm template you loose much of the functionality. DevExpress grid is extremely full of bugs. A good advice is to stay away from DevExpress.